# How can ''mycmd'' and ''echo $(mycmd)'' have different output in zsh?

Tags: zsh

Consider the following zsh script:

```bash
echo $(echo "yes")
```

Now, `echo` takes a string and turns it into standard output. On the other hand, the `$(X)` notation evaluates `X` and turns its standard output into a string.

Expectedly, the standard output is as follows:

```
 dteiml@DominiksMBP2019 ~ echo $(echo "yes")
yes
```

So far so good.

Now consider the following script involving [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat). bat is a pretty-prettier for cat, kind of like Pygments.

```bash
echo "yes" | bat
```

The standard output is as follows:

```
 dteiml@DominiksMBP2019 ~ echo "yes" | bat
───────┬─────────────────────────────────
       │ STDIN
───────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1   │ yes
───────┴─────────────────────────────────
```

So I would expect the following command:

```bash
echo $(echo "yes" | bat)
```

to produce the same output (pretty-formatted). However, it just outputs "yes":

```
dteiml@DominiksMBP2019 ~ echo $(echo "yes" | bat)
yes
```

Based on the above, this is unexpected. Does it use some zsh api that would allow it to determine if it's being executed inside a `$(X)` block, or something else?

PS I don't really need this for anything, just trying to get a better understanding of bash/zsh.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `bat` is checking whether its output is a TTY and declining to reformat for human-targeted output when the output is a FIFO instead of a TTY. This isn't a bash/zsh choice, it's a bat choice.

Comment: That said, if your shell were bash instead of zsh and bat _did_ create the table in question (instead of doing that only if `isatty(1)` is true), you'd have some serious bugs unless you changed your code to `echo "$(echo "yes" | bat)"` _with the quotes_.

Comment: (Please only tag one or the other of bash and zsh, not both at the same time; they're not mutually compatible)

Comment: (this is the same as how `ls --color=auto` only writes color-formatting when going straight to a terminal, not when writing to a pipe).

Comment: ...for where `bat` performs this check, see https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/blob/08c91a116c7513518e857c5e3b9d629e81d98f80/src/bin/bat/app.rs#L163-L180, using a variable populated at https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/blob/08c91a116c7513518e857c5e3b9d629e81d98f80/src/bin/bat/app.rs#L44 -- `atty::is(Stream::Stdout)`

Comment: ...and the library it calls into is invoking `libc::isatty(fd)` at https://docs.rs/atty/0.2.14/src/atty/lib.rs.html#48

Comment: ...and just to emphasize something that may have been implicit above: `isatty()` isn't communicating with the calling shell: it still works if there _is_ no copy of bash or zsh or any other shell running as a parent process; rather, it's communicating with the operating system kernel to ask if stdout is pointing to a TTY object (`/dev/pty*` etc) as opposed to any other kind of file handle. (Or, rather, it's using the libc, which is responsible for knowing how the local OS communicates that, whether it requires a syscall or not).